# cucumber takes unusually more time to step in to the definition file

Tags: java, cucumber

cucumber takes unusually more time to step in to the definition file, almost it takes 5 minutes for every F3 from the feature file to corresponding code file. Please advise.

Comment: Can u add more details? hard to suggest anything based on what is mentioned in the question.

Comment: Cucumber Version : 0.0.22.201806032001, Java IDE : Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers[Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)]. Hope this gives some info, let me know if you need any specific details.